# Invoke-Expression, not all output returned to variable

Tags: git, powershell, io-redirection, stderr, powershell-6.0

I'm using some GIT commands in my PowerShell scripts. Most of the time I'm calling the GIT commands via `Invoke-Expression` so that I, e.g.

- can parse the output, or/and
- forward the out to a logging method.

At some GIT commands I recognized that not all output is returned via `Invoke-Expression` though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6#outputs) states:

> Outputs
>
> PSObject
>
> Returns the output that is generated by the invoked command (the value of the Command parameter).

Here is an example:

```
> $x = iex "git fetch --all"
remote: Enumerating objects: 7, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
```

Content of `$x`:

```
> $x
Fetching origin
Fetching upstream
```

So the main information is not returned to `$x`. I can't imagine that `git fetch --all` is returning the main information via `stderr` (wouldn't make sense ...).

I also found this PowerShell [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979395/output-all-invoke-expression-in-powershell-v2), which is unanswered and the used PowerShell version is 2.

Used PowerShell version:

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

How can I force `Invoke-Expression` to return the whole output?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[PowerShell Capture Git Output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309)", with [Git 2.16 (Q1 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232450/6309), you can try and set first:

```
set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1
```

Then in your Powershell script, you should get both stdout and stderr outputs,

See also [`dahlbyk/posh-git` issue 109](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/109#issuecomment-478088388) for a more Powershell-like example:

```
$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'
```

Answer (score 3):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647960/45375) works well with `git`, specifically, but it's worth discussing **a generic solution**:

---

Note: **[`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)** and there is ***no* reason to use it for invocation of external programs**: just invoke them *directly* and assign to a variable:

```
$capturedStdout = git ... # capture git's stdout output as an array of lines
```

As has been noted, **`git` outputs *status* information to *stderr***, whereas *data* goes to stdout; **a PowerShell variable assignment only captures *stdout* output**.<sup>[1]</sup>

**To capture a *combination* of stdout and stderr**, interleaved, as it would print to the terminal, you can **use redirection `2>&1`**, as in other shells, to merge the error stream / stderr (`2`) into (`>&`) the data output stream (stdout equivalent, `1` - see [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)):

```
$combinedOutput = git fetch --all 2>&1
```

<sup>**Caveat**: In PowerShell versions up to v7.1, if `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` happens to be in effect, the use of `2>` unexpectedly triggers a terminating error; this problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #4002](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002).</sup>

There are non-obvious differences to the behavior of other shells, however:

- The **output will be an *array of lines***, not a single, multi-line string,

  - Note: As of PowerShell 7.2 - external-program output is *invariably* interpreted as *text* (strings) - there is no support for raw binary output; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- Lines that originated from *stdout* are represented as *strings*, as expected, but lines originating from *stderr* are actually [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances, though they *print* like strings and on *conversion* to strings do reproduce the original line, such as when sending the result to an external program.
  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68106198/45375) shows how to separate the captured lines by stream of origin (assuming stdout and stderr were merged).
- Being able to capture stderr output separately *in a variable* is desirable, which isn't supported as of PowerShell 7.2.x, however. Adding future support, along the lines of `2>variable:errs`, is the subject of [GitHub issue #4332](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332).

The **array-based result can be advantageous for parsing**; e.g., to find a line that contains the word `unpacking`:

```
PS> $combinedOutput -match 'unpacking'
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
```

<sup>Note: If there's a chance that only *one* line was output, use `@($combinedOutput) -match 'unpacking'`</sup>

If you prefer **to receive a single, multi-line string** instead:

```
$combinedOutput = (git fetch --all 2>&1) -join "`n"  # \n (LF); or: [Environment]::NewLine
```

If you don't mind a *trailing newline* as part of the string, you can more simply use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string):<sup>[2]</sup>

```
$combinedOutput = git fetch --all 2>&1 | Out-String
```

*Caveat*: **In *Windows PowerShell* this won't work as expected if stderr lines are present**, as they are rendered like PowerShell *error records* (this problem has been fixed in *PowerShell (Core) 6+*); run `cmd /c 'echo data & echo err >&2' 2>&1 | Out-String` to see the problem. Use the `` -join "`n" `` solution to avoid the problem.

---

Note:

- As usual, **irrespective of what redirections you use, determining whether an external-program call *succeeded or failed* should be based *only* on its *exit code***, reflected in PowerShell's [automatic **`$LASTEXITCODE`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode): By convention (which most, but not all programs observe), `0` indicates *success* and and any *nonzero* value failure (a notable exception is `robocopy` which uses several nonzero exit codes to communicate additional information in the *success* case).

---

<sup>[1] For comprehensive information on capturing output from external programs in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980675/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] This problematic `Out-String` behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

try this (without iex)

```
$x=git fetch --all
```

Comment: Suggesting direct invocation instead of the pointless use of `Invoke-Expression` is a good idea, but the OP's main problem is the inability to also capture _stderr_ output.