# PowerShell: System.Diagnostics.Process takes forever to run

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell scripts, the basic function is to run curl.exe to copy a file from remote ftp server to local.
At first, I used the following code to run curl.exe:

```
$curlPath = "curl.exe"
$curlArgs = "sftp://download.url.com/filename_20220618.zip --user username:psw -o D:\filename_20220618.zip -k"
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = $curlPath
$pinfo.Arguments = $curlArgs
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$curlProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$curlProcess.StartInfo = $pinfo
$curlProcess.Start() | Out-Null
$curlProcess.WaitForExit()
```

The code sometimes works. But most of the time will pending forever. I don't known the cause.
When the code works, I can get error message from $curlProcess.StandError if $curlProcess.ExitCode is not 0.

To work around, I decided to use

```
$curlPath = "curl.exe"
$curlArgs = "sftp://download.url.com/filename_20220618.zip --user username:psw -o D:\filename_20220618.zip -k"
$curlProcess = Start-Process $curlPath -ArgumentList $curlArgs -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
```

The above codes worked. The only problem is when  $curlProcess.ExistCode is not 0, I cannot get the error message. $curlProcess.StandError is always empty.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**To synchronously execute *console applications* and capture their output, call them *directly*, do *not* use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on)** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for background information, and
[GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) for guidance on when use of  `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

*Direct* invocation:

- *implicitly* executes console applications *synchronously* (in a blocking fashion)
- connects a console application's stdout and stderr streams to PowerShell streams, which passes them through to the host (display) by default, but also allows:

  - *capturing* stdout output, simply by piping it to another command or capturing it in a variable (e.g., `$var = curl.exe ...`); note that the output is captured as *lines* of text, with a single line getting captured as-is, and two or more getting captured as an *array* of lines.
  - *redirecting* stderr output, either to a *file* (e.g., `2>errs.txt`) or by merging it into the success output stream (`2>&1`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57648600/45375) for more information.
- makes the process exit code available via the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

```
# Prints both stdout and stderr to the display.
# $LASTEXITCODE reflects the process exit code.
curl.exe sftp://download.url.com/filename_20220618.zip --user username:psw -o D:\filename_20220618.zip -k
```